# jquery.post() processing flow

Tags: jquery

I have a page that is posting a JSON to a cfc, and getting a success/fail message back. The array that the JSON is built from contains the ID's of the input fields that were updated.  I am changing the background color of the elements to alert the users that an update was made, but the problem arises when the the user posts more changes without leaving the page.  The array still contains the data from the previous post, and no matter what or where I try to clear the array, the changing of the background stops working.

Here is the code:

```
$("input").change(function(){
    theArray.push({
       'id':$(this).attr('id'),
       'value':$(this).val()
    });

});

$("#edit_button").click(function(){
    if(theArray.length >0){
        theArray.push({
           //some processing information to the cfc
        });
        theJson = JSON.stringify(theArray);
        $.post("CFCs/fund_profile.cfc",
            {
                method:"updateProfile",
                data:theJson
            },
            function(data){
            if(data.HASERROR == 1){
                $("#messageDiv").empty().html(data.MESSAGE);
            }
            else{
                $("#messageDiv").empty().html(data.MESSAGE);
                theArray.pop();//removing the cfc processing information
                for(var i = 0; i <= theArray.length; i++){
                    var $el = $("#" = theArray[i].id).parent().parent().css('background','red');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $el.css('background','');
                        $("#messageDiv").empty();
                    },5000);
                }
            }
         },
         "json");
        //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES (I THINK)
        //I HAVE TRIED THE FOLLOWING:
        var arrayLen = theArray.length;
        for(var j = 0;j <= arrayLen; j++){
            theArray.pop();
        }//DOESN'T WORK

        theArray.length = 0;
        //DOESN'T WORK

        for(var j = 0;j <= arrayLen; j++){
            theArray.shift();
        }//DOESN'T WORK
    }
});
```

If I remove the code to clear the array, the background change happens, but the array never loses that element, and will always show that element as being updated.  If I keep it the background changes doesn't happen at all.

I"m sure it is something simple that I am missing, but I'm frustrated about it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The first 4 lines of code you posted are not valid. Also, what is `edit_button` supposed to refer to? do you have a `<edit_button>` tag?

Comment: `<cfinput type="button" name="edit_button" id="edit_button" value="Update Profile" >`

Comment: Then it should be `$("#edit_button")`

Comment: OK, I fixed a few typo. I didn't copy and paste the code. sorry.

Comment: Ok now your code makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this inside of your post statement after the if/else statement:

```
theArray = [];
```

That effectively makes the array empty. No need for looping through it.

Also, as pointed out by David, it has to be inside of the success of the post, not after it.

**Edit:**
Your for loop isn't executing exactly as you expect it to, the setTimeout should only affect the last element. To solve that, switch to a `$.each`, or create an anonymous function inside of your for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i <= theArray.length; i++){
    (function(i){
        var $el = $("#" = theArray[i].id).parent().parent().css('background','red');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $el.css('background','');
            $("#messageDiv").empty();
        },5000);
    })(i);
}
```

**One more note:**
If someone submits a second set of data to the server before the first one is complete, things may get very messed up due to both cases using the same array. David touched on that on his answer pretty well. Maybe on the click event you should immediately make a copy of the array and then clear the original, leaving it open for use by the next click.

Example (possibly working, not tested):

```
var theArray = [];
$("input").change(function() {
    theArray.push({
        'id': $(this).attr('id'),
        'value': $(this).val()
    });

});

$("#edit_button").click(function() {
    var myArray = $.extend([], theArray, true); // get a copy of theArray
    theArray = []; // empty theArray
    if (myArray.length > 0) {
        myArray.push({
            //some processing information to the cfc
        });
        theJson = JSON.stringify(myArray);
        $.post("CFCs/fund_profile.cfc", {
            method: "updateProfile",
            data: theJson
        }, function(data) {
            if (data.HASERROR == 1) {
                $("#messageDiv").empty().html(data.MESSAGE);
            }
            else {
                $("#messageDiv").empty().html(data.MESSAGE);
                myArray.pop(); //removing the cfc processing information
                var $el = $([]);
                for (var i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++) {
                    $el.add("#" = myArray[i].id);
                }
                $el = $el.parent().parent().css('background','red');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $el.css('background','');
                    $("#messageDiv").empty();
                },5000);
            }
        }, "json");
    }
});
```

**Edit** updated for loop in last statement, should be easier to understand.

Comment: @Kevin_B You said, "the setTimeout should only affect the last element", no I want ALL elements in the array to get a red background, and then change back to transparent background after the 5 seconds.  This is basically to alert the user that the update actually happened.  That is why it is in the for loop, because I can't think of a better why to do it.  The changing of the background is the crux of this post.  It works the first time, but keeps the old records in the array, which causes elements to show that they were updated, but really updated previously.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @RobM Right, the way your loop was written, it would only affect the last one. The way i re-wrote it, it will affect them all.

Answer (score 2):

According to the layout of the code you posted (which isn't entirely valid, so I'm concerned that it's not the *actual* code you're using), you're handling the post-conditions of the AJAX call in the wrong place.  It's *outside* of the `$.post()` callback function, so it's not happening (or not guaranteed to happen) in the same order.  Keep in mind that AJAX is *asynchronous*, so the code which has your comments indicating what works or doesn't work is happening *before* the callback function.

I'd recommend keeping the callback function in the `$.post()` as autonomous as possible.  Instead of having it interact with the array in JavaScript, have the server return an array in the JSON response of elements being updated.  Then the callback function can happily interact with those elements on its own and other instances of the callback function which are spawned in the interim don't get in its way.

So, essentially, you'd keep the clearing of the array where you have it now, outside of the `$.post()` callback, so it would happen immediately after the AJAX call is made (and in probably all cases before it returns).  You'd modify the server-side code to return affected IDs.  And the `data` argument being passed to the callback function would contain those IDs and you'd use that to interact with the CSS, instead of using `theArray` directly.

Comment: I don't really want to modify the server side code to return the id's because the structure of the JSON getting returned now only contains two pieces of information `{"HASERROR":"0","MESSAGE":"Records have been updated"}`.  Honestly, I thought about doing that, but why when I already have an array that contains all of the information that I need.

Comment: @RobM: Fair enough.  In that case you'll probably want to make a copy of that local array within the scope of the callback function, the goal still being to make that function fully encapsulated so that asynchronous instances of the function have all of the data they each need internally without getting in each other's way.  So you'll want to copy (clone) `theArray` within the `click` handler and access that copy within the callback.